# Pasar valor de una función en js a php

Tags: php, javascript, php5

Buenas como pueden ver estoy intentando coger la localización del usuario, pero no se (soy muy novato) es como podría pasar la información que me recoge en la función showPosition(position) y poder trabajar con los datos que recoja en php. (dejo el codigo completo de lo que he intentado)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb18030">
    <title>Geolocalizacion</title>
</head>

<body>



<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}


  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }


var prueba_js = 'prueba';
var latitudfer_js = getCurrentPosition.coords.latitude;
</script>

<?php
        $prueba_PHP = "<script> document.writeln(prueba_js); </script>"; // igualar el valor de la variable JavaScript a PHP 
        $latitudfer_PHP = "<script> document.writeln(navigator.geolocation.coords.latitude); </script>"; // igualar el valor de la variable JavaScript a PHP

    echo $prueba_PHP;   // muestra el resultado 
    echo "</br></br>";   // salto 
    echo $latitudfer_PHP;   // muestra el resultado 
    echo "</br></br>";   // salto 
    echo $mensaje;   // muestra el resultado 
    echo "</br></br>";   // salto 
?>

<script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que identes mejor el código, y nombres a las variables con sentido. Cuesta un poco leer el código y entender que hace cada variable si las nombras a casi todas "prueba".

Comment: PHP no puede obtener variables directamente de JS, porque se ejecutan en diferentes contextos. Lo que haces con `$prueba_PHP = "<script> document.writeln(prueba_js); </script>"; echo $rpueba_PHP;` es generar contenido que luego es interpretado por el navegador. Tendrías que buscar una opción para obtener esos datos directamente en PHP o recibirlos por AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

### Intro

Cuando hagas desarrollo web tienes que tener claro que existen dos mundos, las cosas que corren en el servidor y las cosas que corren en el cliente (browser). PHP es un lenguaje que corre en el servidor y JS un lenguaje que corre en el cliente (existe Node.js pero es otro tema).

Un archivo PHP que incluye JS o HTML primero es interpretado por el servidor, hará todo lo que este dentro de él  y luego le enviará el resultado al browser pero SIN PHP. Como verás ya no hay forma en la que se puedan comunicar tu PHP y tu JS...

### Solución

Sin embargo puedes lograr que se comuniquen (más o menos)... necesitas utilizar AJAX y crear un WS (web service). Puedes implementar fácilmente una llamada AJAX con JQUERY:
[JQUERY Webpage](https://jquery.com/)

#### Diseño

[image: Arch Front + WS]

Como se muestra en e diagrama:

1. El HTML+**JS**+AJAX toma los datos de geolocalización del usuario.
2. El HTML+**JS**+AJAX guarda esos datos en un array o un par de variables
3. El HTML+JS+**AJAX** envía esos datos al WS(PHP)
4. El WS hará los cálculos que requiera
5. El WS hace un echo de la información resultante
6. El HTML+JS+**AJAX** recibe los datos
7. El HTML+**JS**+AJAX modfica el HTML para mostrar los datos

### Implementación Front

- Incluye JQUERY en tu HTML
- Agrega tu data a un arreglo
- Haz la llamada AJAX al WS

```
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "path/to/ws",
        dataType: "json", //si tu respuesta viene en json
        data: dataArray
    }).done(function(response){
        #Do something
    });
```

### Implementación WS

- El ws tomará las variables del arreglo global $_POST
- Debes tener bloques de validación como ifs y try-catch
- El ws hará los cálculos necesarios
- El ws hará un echo y si quieres que se imprima como JSON aplica la función json_encode

```
    if (isset($_POST["geo_dato1"])){
        $suma = $_POST["geo_dato1"] + $_POST["geo_dato1"];
        $resta = $_POST["geo_dato1"] - 2;
    
        $respuesta["dato1"] = $suma;
        $respuesta["dato2"] = $resta;
    }else{
        $respuesta["error"] = "error";
    }
    
    echo json_encode($respuesta);
```